# If I stay on 7.1.2 firmware, should I backup My Apps to Itunes?

Tags: itunes, backup, data-synchronization

I have an app installed on my device running iOS 7.1.2.
Say I delete the app.
In a few months I CANNOT download the app without updating to iOS 8.

If I "backup the app" using Sync onto Itunes, can I recover the app compatible with 7.1.2?
or will it still require me to have iOS 8?

Alternate Q: If restoring the app via Itunes sync fails, what Other methods can I save and recover the older version of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately by "backing up the app" it only backs up the data the app has. You can go into your finder and locate the app and save that in another location and when you need it inport it into iTunes. Just remember to not update the app.

Finder/username/music/itunes/itunes media/mobile applications

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a version of a product in the past, that is not supported anymore, iTunes should know that and allow you to later download that older version of the product.

I have done this with '**Find my iPhone**' and '**Find my Friends**':
Trying to install a fresh iPhone-4 with a new Apple-ID, it didn't let me
install those apps because the minimum requirement was iOS 8.0 at that time,
and iPhone-4 cannot be upgraded to iOS 8.x at all.

**The solution was**:

1. If needed, **[switch iTunes account](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201248)** to one that has downloaded this
   older version in the past
2. Download the app (will get the message saying this version is too new,
   with an option to **Download** an older version)
3. If needed, switch back to the original iTunes account
   (you will not be able to upgrade this App, which is not relevant in this case anyhow).

Cheers